# How do I clean log files from dockerised ELK?

Tags: docker, elastic-stack, elk

I'm using a [docker-elk](https://github.com/deviantony/docker-elk) and I'd like to clean all the log files, but I'm not sure where they're stored. The funny thing is, when I stop and remove all the docker containers and then run them from the docker-compose file, the ELK server still contains all the old logs. Why is that?

Here's my docker-compose.yml for reference:

```
version: '3.2'

services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: volume
        source: elasticsearch
        target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      ES_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
      ELASTIC_PASSWORD: changeme
      # Use single node discovery in order to disable production mode and avoid bootstrap checks
      # see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/bootstrap-checks.html
      discovery.type: single-node
    network_mode: "host"
    # networks:
    #   - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/config/logstash.yml
        target: /usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml
        read_only: true
      - type: bind
        source: ./logstash/pipeline
        target: /usr/share/logstash/pipeline
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
    environment:
      LS_JAVA_OPTS: "-Xmx256m -Xms256m"
    network_mode: "host"
    # networks:
    #   - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
      args:
        ELK_VERSION: $ELK_VERSION
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ./kibana/config/kibana.yml
        target: /usr/share/kibana/config/kibana.yml
        read_only: true
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    network_mode: "host"
    # networks:
    #   - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch:
```

Comment: did yo use mounting in docker-compose file? can you check log file `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log ` ?

Comment: Yes I have. In the elasticsearch container, a volume has been mounted to `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data`. There's a `/usr/share/elasticsearch/logs/` folder with log files like gc.log, gc.log.00, gc.log.01, etc, but the contents don't seem to resemble logs. As for `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log`, no such directory exists

Comment: I see so its becuase of persistent storage `/usr/share/elasticsearch/data.` docker-compose remove does not remove persistent storage,you need to clean this from host.

Comment: I'm not sure how to clean it from the host. In my docker-compose.yml, the source volume is not a directory on my folder, it's a volume delcared in the file: `source: elasticsearch`, `target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data`. Posted my docker-compose.yml for a better picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mounted volume:

```
  - type: volume
    source: elasticsearch
    target: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

I think if you remove this volume and rebuild your docker-compose you'll get fresh container with no data.

Answer (score 0):

While non-Docker Elasticsearch logs to `/var/log/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.log` by default (on Linux), the Docker containers write their logs to `STDOUT` , which is generally a [Docker best practice](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/).

Those logs should be in `/var/lib/docker/containers/`, but note that on Mac this is inside the small VM layer that Docker is using, so you can't access it directly.

How do you "stop and remove all the docker containers" and still "the ELK server still contains all the old logs"? `docker-compose down -v` should remove everything and do you see the logs in `docker logs` or somewhere else?